# Problems with the div tag in CSS and inline borders that go around the div

Tags: html, css, tags, xhtml

This is my first time using HTML with CSS inline style. Basically I am trying to use a div tag with an inline style to cause it to have a double lined border and one half of a letter width padding offsetting the text.

I thought maybe I should start the div tag using an inline style rule, and a double border. For example:

```
<div>
<div style=border:double;padding:0em,3px></div>
```

Is that a correct approach?

Comment: Never use inline css. It is really very bad idea. What output you expected?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question but here's your code cleaned up.. `style="border-style: double; padding: 0em 3px;"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<hr>` to create a horizontal rule and style it to make it double lined.

```
hr {
    padding: 0em 3px;
    border: none;
    border-top: double #000;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use inline ,just use it like this

```
<div style="border:4px double black;width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always put quotes around attribute values. There is no reason not to. (Originally, quotes were meant to be omittable around simple values, for instance `height=30`, never around phrases that contained colons and semicolons and greater-than signs and stuff...)

Also, you have an error in the paddings: those are not separated by commas.

Then if you use the `border` notation, which is a shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`, the browser will choose default values for the properties you don't specify. In this case, `medium` for the `border-width` and `currentColor` for the `border-color`. If that is what you had planned, OK. But if you don't know beforehand how thick a `medium` border is exactly, you should provide a width yourself.
See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border).

For double borders, multiples of 3px work best, since that's what you need minimally (1 px for each of the lines and 1 px in between). With other widths, different browsers may divide the widths differently, so that you may get thicker lines and less space in between on some browsers than on others.

Edit:
WRT the comment, if you want the div to take up the right half of the window, you can do something like this. Using a left margin of `auto` and a right margin of `0`, the div will be flushed to the right.
Note that I also used a padding of `.5ch` for "one half of a letter width", which is better than 3px hardcoded.

```css
.styled {
  border:3px double;
  width:50%;
  padding:.5ch 0;
  margin:0 0 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled"></div>
<hr/>
```

Or, if using a float is more desirable:

```css
.styled {
  border:3px double;
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  padding:.5ch 0;
  margin-bottom:1em;
}
.styled + * {
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled"></div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: I wanted to position the box horizontally so that it uses only the right half of the page. I thought maybe I could use the float property and then escaping, so that the box appears above the horizontal rule, which is at the end of the page.

Comment: @AshleeHarlow You should edit the question and put that in. In your question, you never mentioned how wide you wanted it to be and that there was a hr which the div should be above.